# ModuleNotFoundError in setup.py when running KubeFlow Pipeline

Tags: python, setuptools, setup.py, python-packaging, kubeflow

I have packaged my Kubeflow code into this structure:

```
awesome_tool/
    |__ setup.py
    |__ src/
            |__ __init__.py
        |__ awesome_tool/
            |__ cli/
            |__ kubeflow/
            |   |__ __init__.py
            |   |__ pipelines/
            |       |__ __init__.py
            |       |__ pipeline.py
            |__ __init__.py
            |__ entrypoints.py
```

The `setup.py` script looks like this:

```py
name = "awesome_tool"
setup(
    name=name,
    version="0.1",
    author="me",
    description="bla bla",
    long_description="bla bla",
    long_description_content_type="text/markdown",
    package_dir={"": "src"},
    packages=find_packages("src", exclude=["*tests"]),
    package_data={
        name: ["*.txt", "*.json", "*.preamble", "*.sql", "py.typed"]
    },
    entry_points={
        "console_scripts": [f"{name} = {name}.entrypoints:main"],
    },
    python_requires=">=3.9",
    install_requires=list(base_requirements | infra_requirements),
    extras_require={
        "dev": list(dev_requirements),
    },
)
```

The issue right now is that it works fine locally (I am able to call the CLI commands declared in `entrypoints.py`), but when trying to run the Kubeflow pipeline, I get this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin/awesome_tool", line 33, in <module>
sys.exit(load_entry_point('awesome-tool', 'console_scripts', 'awesome_tool')())
File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/bin/awesome_tool", line 25, in importlib_load_entry_point
return next(matches).load()
File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.10/importlib/metadata/__init__.py", line 171, in load
module = import_module(match.group('module'))
File "/opt/conda/envs/rapids/lib/python3.10/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1050, in _gcd_import
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1027, in _find_and_load
File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1004, in _find_and_load_unlocked
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'awesome_tool.entrypoints'
Job is running.
```

Is this an issue with a different path that Kubeflow is reading from? Has anyone had this issue before?

Comment: You should not need any `src/__init__.py` file, because `src` is most likely not an import package, I assume no one wants to `import src`.